# Where the Toolbar is created in BluetoothLeGatt - Android App

Tags: android

I'm using the official BluetoothLeGatt - Android App example. Does anyone know that where the toolbar (main.xml) is created, please? Also, I created a login Activity as the entry point of the App (i.e. before DeviceScanActivity.java). When I open the App, I could see the login page. However, there is a toolbar displayed on the login page, too. Why and how to remove it, please?

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

public void login_btn(View view){
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceScanActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Check the AndroidManifest to see which theme the Activity has. It most likelly has a Theme that has a Toolbar in it. Alternatively look at `styles.xml` or `themes.xml`. Last but not least, if you link to the repository where this example is located, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Hi, @MartinMarconcini. Thanks for your response. In AndroidManifest, it uses `android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`.  If delete them, the toolbar has a black background and **com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.L...** (too long to see the full name). **(1)** how to delete the toolbar entirely for all activities **(2)** how to delete the toolbar for the 1st page, but keep the toolbar for all other pages, please? The BluetoothLeGatt example GitHub link is [here](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothLeGatt). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Bar you're seeing is the default ActionBar provided by the Activity thanks to the default theme. As you have stated, this Theme is `Theme.Holo.Light`.

I suggest you try changing it to one of the various Material Design themes:

E.g.:
Edit your `themes.xml` and edit/create one for your app:

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Notice I used `NoActionBar`. This will effectively remove the action bar for all Activities that use this Theme. You can make this the "default" for all activities (q1 in your comment) by changing in the Manifest, the line you pasted there: `android:theme="..."` and replacing the ... with your theme.

As for removing it from "one" place, you have choices here:

1. Have the "one place" use a different theme. Again if these are activities, you can override the Theme of an activity in your Android Manifest:

```
    <activity
            android:name=".IDontWantToolbarActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

(It would likely be better if you create your own "NoActionBar" theme extension in `themes.xml` like:

```
// This is your "default" theme with an ActionBar.
<style name="Theme.YourNormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

You can override it like this:

```
<style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Or even better:

```
   <style name="Theme.YourNormalTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

You can also use a ThemeOverlay:

```
<style name="Theme.YourNormalTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

I recommend you get acquainted with Themes, Styles, and Attributes by reading a Google's emploee [article on Medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-styling-themes-vs-styles-ebe05f917578) about this.

Alternatively, you can use a NoActionBar theme globally, but decide to include one in a specific fragment/activity. In these instances (and in most cases) you'd want to use NoActionBar theme and include a `Toolbar` (source: [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar)) in your layout and wire it (see documentation).